# Rotated icon snaps back after animation completes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

Trying to animate my icon to rotate 45 degree upon a click event and after you click it again it rotates back. Succesfully getting my initial rotation upon the click, however without clicking, after the animation finishes it snaps back to its original state.

HTML

```
<div class="trip-detail--icon-plus">
  <span class="transport--plus spin" ng-class="{active:showActionOptions}"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.spin::before {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
  -o-transition: transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}


.spin.active::before {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: create js fiddle if possible...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do would require a CSS hack to imitate a click event
You can read on [CSS Click events](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/)

You can also view my solution on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackEnigma/kony575n/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<label for="toggle-1">
  <div>Control me</div>
</label>
```

Here is the CSS code

```
/* Checkbox Hack */
input[type=checkbox] {   
  position: absolute;   
  top: -9999px;   
  left: -9999px;
}

label {   
  display: inline-block;  
  margin: 60px 0 10px 0;  
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Default State */
div {   
  background: green;   
  width: 400px;   height: 100px;   
  line-height: 100px;   
  color: white;   
  text-align: center;   
  transition: transform 2s ease; 
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label div {   
  background: red;   
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

The only important lines in the CSS code are the `toggled state`, `checkbox hack` and `transition` property in the div default state

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Since you're using javascript to handle click events, it is much easier to accomplish using `animation` instead of a `transition` I don't know what your click handler looks like but you stated that it is toggling different classes so this is the code I wrote

Here's the CSS code

```
@keyframes spin-forward {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } to {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-backword {
  from {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  } to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.spin-right {
  animation: spin-forward 2s ease forwards;
}

.spin-left {
  animation: spin-backword 2s ease forwards;
}
```

Here's the Javascript code

```
$(function() {
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var klass = this.className;
    if (klass === "") {
      el.addClass('spin-right');
    } else if (klass === 'spin-right') {
      el.attr('class', 'spin-left');
    } else {
      el.attr('class', 'spin-right');
    }
  });
});
```

The reason why `animation` is better is because it offers more control. The `forwards` value allows you to keep an element in the new state after the animation finishes.

You can check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackEnigma/b2svwoto/)

Hope this solves it

Comment: I'm not imitating a click event, there is a click event occurring which toggles the value of the Ng class either true/false

Comment: Check the new answer and Fiddle. If you need more help you could show me your click handler so I can revise the code to use that. Hope this helps you accomplish your task :)